# Access to each separate channel in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an image with 3 channels (img) and another one with a single channel (ch1).

```
    Mat img(5,5,CV_64FC3);
    Mat ch1 (5,5,CV_64FC1);
```

Is there any efficient way (not using for loop) to copy the first channel of **img** to **ch1**?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a function called [cvMixChannels](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=mixchannels#mixchannels). You'll need to see implementation in the source code, but I bet it is well optimized.

Comment: Thank you Jacek. It seems, I can complete my task using mixChannels

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried both split and mixChannels. And, they throw error! do you have any idea, what can be the reason?

Comment: I did mistake in types. instead of using CV_32FC1, I used CV_64FC1.
Thank you for your helps

Comment: Use the C++ API whenever possible (the C API is going to be deprecated soon): It is thus cv::mixChannels, not cvMixChannels. Same goes for cvSplit, use cv::split from core.hpp instead.

Answer (score 55):

In fact, if you just want to copy one of the channels or split the color image in 3 different channels, `CvSplit()` is more appropriate (I mean simple to use).

```
Mat img(5,5,CV_64FC3);
Mat ch1, ch2, ch3;
// "channels" is a vector of 3 Mat arrays:
vector<Mat> channels(3);
// split img:
split(img, channels);
// get the channels (dont forget they follow BGR order in OpenCV)
ch1 = channels[0];
ch2 = channels[1];
ch3 = channels[2];
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use split function and then put zeros to the channels u want to ignore. This will result dispalying one channels out of three. See below..

For example:

```
Mat img, chans[3]; 
img = imread(.....);  //make sure its loaded with an image

//split the channels in order to manipulate them
split(img, chans);

//by default opencv put channels in BGR order , so in your situation you want to copy the first channel which is blue. Set green and red channels elements to zero.
chans[1]=Mat::zeros(img.rows, img.cols, CV_8UC1); // green channel is set to 0
chans[2]=Mat::zeros(img.rows, img.cols, CV_8UC1);// red channel is set to 0

//then merge them back
merge(chans, 3, img);

//display 
imshow("BLUE CHAN", img);
cvWaitKey();
```

Comment: It is a better answer, and improves upon the answer with the most votes (which isn't the accepted one) by putting the complementary function cv::merge() in it too (though maybe just editing that other answer would be better, but the user lacks the rep points?)

Answer (score 12):

You can access a specific channel, it works faster than the `split` operation

```
Mat img(5,5,CV_64FC3);
Mat ch1;
int channelIdx = 0;
extractChannel(img, ch1, channelIdx); // extract specific channel

// or extract them all
vector<Mat> channels(3);
split(img, channels);
cout << channels[0].size() << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

A simpler one if you have a RGB with 3 channels is cvSplit() if i'm not wrong, you have less to configure... (and i think it is also well optimized).

I would use cvMixChannel() for "harder" tasks... :p (i know i am lazy).

[here is the documentation for cvSplit()](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/core_operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=split#cvSplit)