# Opening uncompressed grayscale videos in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, avi, grayscale

I have a medical device that saves uncompressed grayscale AVI videos on which I would like to conduct some offline analyses. The pixels in the videos are unsigned 8 bit with only one color channel. When I use OpenCV's VideoCapture class and the read method to extract frames from these videos, I get matrices that have 3 color channels and are low contrast,sheared versions of the originals. I have tried cvtCOlor to convert the 3 color channel to grayscale but that not solve the problem. If I change the number of channels in the video to 3 (using MATLAB), this problem goes away.
Is there a method to read in frames from the uncompressed grayscale single channel video without having to increase the number of channels?
I am running OpenCV 2.3.1 on a PC runniNg ubuntu 12.04.

Thank you in advance

cheers

gkr

Comment: possible duplicate of [opencv VideoCapture.set greyscale?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159506/opencv-videocapture-set-greyscale)

Answer (score 0):

From the [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-read):

> VideoCapture::read() calls grab() and retrieve() in one call

Note sure, but if you try using grab() and then [retrieve() with 1 channel Mat](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-retrieve), maybe it can solve the problem.